# Sum of all possible $k$-fold products for a set of $n$ integers

Tags: number-theory

Here is something I stumbled upon and I am wondering if there is a closed formula for the expression considered or whether this quantity has a name and been studied in the literature somewhere.

Assume given integers $1\leq k\leq n$. Consider
$$G(k,n)=\sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2<\dots<i_k\leq n}i_1i_2\dots i_k.$$
For $k=1$ one gets the very well known formula
$$G(1,n)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$

For $k=2$, I get the formula
$$G(2,n)=\sum_{i=1}^n{i\frac{(n-i)(n+i+1)}{2}}.$$

> Do these numbers have a name? What about formulas for other values of
>   $k$?

Comment: Thank you! Should have seen that (been blind there). It would still be interesting for me to know if evaluating them at (1,2,...n) gives some interesting properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unsigned stirling numbers of the first kind.

$G(1,n) = -s(n+1,n), G(2,n) = s(n+1,n-1)$ and so on.

For properties see Wikipedia and OEIS.

Answer (score 0):

Here  is some  of the  algebra that  is involved.  We have  from first
principles that

$$H(n, k) = [z^k] \prod_{q=1}^n (1+qz).$$

This is

$$[z^k] z^n \prod_{q=1}^n (1/z+q)
= [z^{k-n}] \prod_{q=1}^n (1/z+q)
\\ = [z^{n-k}] \prod_{q=1}^n (z+q)
= [z^{n-k+1}] \prod_{q=0}^n (z+q)$$

which is equal to

$${n+1\brack n-k+1}$$

by inspection.